# Linear independence of Wishart matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, probability-distributions, random-matrices

Let $W\sim W_n(I,d)$ be a real Wishart matrix of an identity covariance matrix and $d$ degrees of freedom, i.e., $W=XX^T$ for $X$ being an $n\times d$ matrix whose entries are i.i.d sampled from a Gaussian distribution. What is the probability that the first $m$ columns spans a $k$-dimensional vector space?

I only have a trivial observation: for $d=n$, $W$ is full-rank with probability 1, so for $m<n$, the first $m$ columns spans an $m$-dimensional space with probability 1. For $d<n$, the matrix $W$ seems to have rank $d$ with probability 1, but I suspect it is false that the first $d$ columns are linearly independent almost surely by the symmetry of Wishart matrices.

Any ideas or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To simplify the question: What about the ordering of all $n,d,k,m$? Are they arbitrary? This would result into many trivial cases.I only see $m,n \leq n$.

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be interesting to consider the case $d<n$.

Comment: "I suspect it is false that the first d columns are linearly independent almost surely by the symmetry of Wishart matrices" - why? For example, $d=1$? I may be too quick but it actually seems to me that the first $d$ columns are linearly independent a.s.